# Rendering into every material preview windown. How is this possible?

Tags: unity, materials

So starting up unity today  has presented me with a extremly wierd bug. The animated material that is rendered by the NVidia HairWorks Integrationg seems to be rendering into every material preview window.[image][image]
I have not done anything special to "achieve" this. Restarting Unity does not help( I tried all the usual stuff). The fur even simulates inside the material preview window if I hit the little play button. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to Unity 2017.2.0p1 seems to have resolved the issue.